# Two vim windows but one instance?

Tags: vim

I want to have "two vim open" because I have multiple monitors.
Also I would like them to share buffers, clipboards, etc.
So I'd like to share the same instance across two different windows.

I have found:

```
vim --remote file.txt
```

but this opens the file in the first vim; it doesn't open a new window within the same vim instance.

How can multiple vim windows share the same instance?

Comment: I am fairly certain that this is not possible. Hopefully someone wiser proves me wrong...

Comment: ;( how can you use vim on multiple monitor? It's terrible ;(

Comment: You can't do that with Vim at the moment but I hear Neovim has that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't believe there is a native way this can be achieved in VIM, there are however other ways to get similar behavior :

1. Expand your terminal to be available on both monitors, that way you can use vim splits and have one split in each monitor and hence work on the same file in both monitors. Although this is probably less cool.
2. Use something like tmux / screen. This way you can just launch multiple terminal windows and have them in separate monitors and connect to the same tmux session from both. You can then edit / view your vim session in either monitor and it will be perfectly mirrored in the other.

Comment: basically i want to be able to edit a file on one monitor and have the same file open in my second monitor with look another part of the file. So tmux don't look like a solution (or I don't have understand how to do that with tmux). I use i3wm so Expend the terminal is not really a easy solution... I have hear about frame in emacs and Evil mode with can probably solve my problem but if it's possible with vim I will appreciate it. Is there a way with "remote editing?"

Comment: You could also just open multiple instances of vim in different monitors.

Comment: You can enable autoread, disable swap, backup to avoid conflicts and do it.